# From circuit diagram to perf board

Tags: circuit-design

I am new to electronic so this question is very basic. I need to make this circuit diagram on perf board. I wonder how to make the series parallel connection on perf board? I can do it on bread board but I really do not know how to make connections on perf board.

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-7/what-is-a-series-parallel-circuit/

[image]

Comment: how would you do it without any board?

Comment: It's easy to do it without any board. It would be just wiring then.

Comment: push the resistor leads through the holes in the perfboard and then connect same way as without perfboard

Comment: You mean solder at the back of the components in the perf board at  the same pattern as I do wiring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would depend on what sort of perfboard you have.

Some perfboard has the holes connected in the same pattern as a plastic breadboard - on those, you just lay out your parts as you would on a breadboard, and solder connections as needed.

Strip board ("Veroboard") has strips of copper connecting all the holes in a row across the board.  On that style, you have to cut the copper strips where you don't want connections.

Another style is "pad per hole" - none of the holes are connected together - they are just individual pads.  You can place your parts as you wish, and use the component leads or other wire to make the necessary connections.

Comment: Thanks alot Peter. If style is pad per hole then I will have to follow the same pattern as of the simple wiring connection as shown in the figure?

Comment: Yes - you could lay out the parts as shown in the schematic, and mkae the appropriate connections using the component leads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to practice some, getting solder to bridge two or more pads is the most difficult part. Also make use of wires to bridge several pads.